# Can I timestamp a particular log ONLY with PM2?

Tags: logging, timestamp, pm2

I have set up timestamps for two node applications in PM2. These timestamps work great, however one of my applications' out log already contains timestamps from the application itself. This results in two timestamps:

```
04-07-2019 09:53:45.074: [32m[2019-07-04 09:53:45.072] [INFO] [default] - MY LOG HERE
```

This particlar log is the only log which already contains timestamps, and it is not feasible for me to remove the timestamps from this application. Is there any way for me to specify in the ecosystem config file of PM2 that I only want timestamps for the error log of this application?

Here is my current ecosystem config file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "Server",
    script : ".../server.js",
    error_file : ".../Server.err.log",
    out_file : ".../Server.out.log",
    log_date_format : 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS'
  }, {
    name : "Watcher",
    script : ".../watch.js",
    error_file : ".../Watcher.err.log",
    out_file : ".../Watcher.out.log",
    log_date_format : 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS',
    restart_delay : 3000
  }]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem if you have two timestamps against an entry in log file?

Comment: It’s just annoying, more than anything. I haven’t found a solution to this so I just deal with it.